# Using a non-zero wedge product to write a set of vectors as a linear combination of another set of vectors in a finite dimensional space.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds

Question:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and let $ \{ v_1, ..., v_r\}$ and $\{w_1, ..., w_r\}$ be two sets of vectors in $V$. Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{r} v_i \wedge w_i = 0$, and that $\{v_1, ... , v_r\}$ are linearly independent. Show that any $w_i$ can be written as a linear combination of $\{v_1, ..., v_r\}$.

Thoughts: 
I need to extract some information about the sum over all of the wedge products being non-zero. I don't know what that is though. I feel like it only tells me that any product of the vectors is non-zero. But I could be wrong.

Also, I feel like I need to define some k-linear and l-linear functions on the space, but I'm not 100% sure if that's necessary.

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: As stated, this result is not true. For example, in the case $r=1$, if $v_1$ and $w_1$ are linearly independent, then $v_1\wedge w_1\ne 0$, but $w_1$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $v_1$.  You need to replace $\ne$ by $=$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_r$ are linearly independent, then there exists a $v = v_r \wedge v_{r-1} \wedge \ldots \wedge v_2 \wedge v_1$ that is nonzero.

Now, take the summation you're given (with the correction that it *should* be equal to zero).

$$v_1 \wedge w_1 + v_2 \wedge w_2 + \ldots + v_r \wedge w_r = 0$$

Wedge onto it $v_r \wedge v_{r-1} \wedge \ldots \wedge v_2$ from the left.  This annihilates all but the first term:

$$v \wedge w_1 = 0$$

Since $v$ corresponds to an $r$-dimensional subspace spanned by $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_r$, the condition $v \wedge w_1 = 0$ implies that $w_1$ has no components outside of this subspace.  Therefore, $w_1$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in this subspace.  Repeat this logic for $w_2, w_3,\ldots, w_r$, and you're done.

Comment: Yes, thank you. As it turns out, it was a typo in my homework. I was wondering why it was so difficult to prove haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace "non-zero" by zero, this is [Cartan's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_lemma).  Hint for proving it: start by extending $\{v_1,\dots,v_r\}$ to a basis for $V$, and then express each $w_i$ in terms of this basis.